# limit memory to load large file and look for a phone number.

Tags: multithreading, genetic-algorithm

There are one billion entries in a very large file, each entry contains a name and his/her phone number.

I need to design system to input a name and quickly find his/her phone number. The tricky part is that, memory can not load a such large file. I am thinking of steaming the data into memory and maybe with some multi-threading technique, however, I am not sure how to decide how many threads I should use.

Haven't found such type of questions online and not sure what's the generic rule to tackle with this question.

Could someone please give me some suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches I can think of:

> Approach 1: Single file reader thread, multiple processing threads

1. Read (stream) the file in a single thread
2. Push each record into a queue as you read them
3. There would be multiple threads monitoring the queue for records,  which will `pop` a record from the queue and check if the name matches
4. If the name matches, it will put the number in a result queue and signal the file reader and other threads to stop further processing
5. If the name doesn't match, it continues onto the next record from the queue

This will ensure you are not using too much memory since records will be popped from the queue by the processing threads. But the issue here is that I/O will most probably be slower than matching the input name, so you might not be able to saturate the processing threads (see the answer to your question about how many threads to choose).

> Approach 2: Multiple file reader threads, multiple processing threads

1. Read the file in multiple threads, by dividing the parts of the file that each thread looks at
2. Rest of the steps are similar to Approach 1

The tricky part here is how to divide the file parts amongst the multiple reader threads. Using a random access file could work, but will be messy.
A better way could be that instead of having one big file, you have multiple smaller files, that can each easily be searched by multiple threads. You could also look at first dividing the file into smaller chunks by the first letter of the first name, and then further into smaller chunks of say 10000 records each.

This approach should give you much better parallelism.

> How many threads should you use

My recommendation would be to read *Java Concurrency in Practice* chapter 11, even if you don't use Java, it is a great resource for the answer to this question:

[Java Concurrency in Practice - Chapter 11](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-concurrency-in/0321349601/ch11.html)

Comment: Hi @rohitvats, this is what I am looking for and it helps me understand the mechanism much better. Awesome answer!